# Cannot accept snapshot.data.docs; ".docs"

Tags: flutter

info: about the flutter version.

```
    [Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/XXX/Development/flutter
    Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (3 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    Engine revision 2f0af37152
    Dart version 2.10.5

    The problem is under for-loop with these 2 lines -> 'text' and 'sender'
    final messageText = message.data['text'];
    final messageSender = message.data['sender']
```

See my learnings code from Angela.
Angela is using the old flutter version .documents and I am using .docs
In the flutter, I cannot find where to choose .documents, only choose .docs
Thank you in advance -  how to fix this error?

```
   child: Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
   children: <Widget>[
   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot. hasData) {
   final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
   List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
   for (var message in messages) {
   final messageText = message.data['text'];
   final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

   final messageWidget =
   Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
   messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
   }
   return Column(
   children: [
   messageWidgets,
   ],
   );
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: ‘snapshot.data.doc(“here your docs id”)

Comment: how you fix it, i have same problem